# What is the folding region marker for Java?

Tags: visual-studio-code

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_folding-regions shows the folding region markers for several languages except Java.

I tried using the closest approximation, ie //#region but it did not work.

Anyone know what is the status for allowing folding region markers in Java?

Comment: To see what are the region markers for any language: "Each language also has snippets available for the markers. Type '#' and invoke code completion to see them."  So type `#` and then Ctrl+Space to see the begin and end region names.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. //#region is the marker for Java, and it works for VS Code 1.45.1.